# How to use new Lollipop SD card access API on devices running KITKAT?

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard

Kit-Kat issue can't write to external SD card,

As mentioned in  [Goolge Document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html)   **To simplify your code on devices running KITKAT or earlier, you can use fromFile(File) which emulates the behavior of a DocumentsProvider** 
The code below (New API) works for Lollipop but how to use the new API for kitkat ?

Also look at [Kit-Kat issue (New API)](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67570)

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 42);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri treeUri = resultData.getData();
        DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromFile(new File("/mnt/extSdCard/Test"));

        // List all existing files inside picked directory
        for (DocumentFile file : pickedDir.listFiles()) {
            Log.d("Tag", "Found file " + file.getName() + " with size " + file.length());
        }

        // Create a new file and write into it
        DocumentFile newFile = pickedDir.createFile("text/plain", "My Novel");
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(newFile.getUri());
            out.write("A long time ago...".getBytes());
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**How to use fromFile(File) ?**

I tried but says  **Failed to createFile: java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)**

Even after adding the permission 
     uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Android version 4.4.2

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromFile(new File("/mnt/extSdCard/Test"));

    // List all existing files inside picked directory
    for (DocumentFile file : pickedDir.listFiles()) {
        Log.d("Tag", "Found file " + file.getName() + " with size " + file.length());
    }

    // Create a new file and write into it
    DocumentFile newFile = pickedDir.createFile("text/plain", "My Novel");
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {

        //Says NullPointerException
        out = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(newFile.getUri());                             out.write("A long time ago...".getBytes());
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The new API only helps people on Lollipop to write to the secondary sdcard, people on KitKat are still [out of luck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744842/how-to-use-the-new-sd-card-access-api-presented-for-lollipop).

> [DocumentFile.fromFile(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html#fromFile%28java.io.File%29)
>
> This doesn't give you any additional
> access to the underlying files beyond what your app already has.

To leverage the new permissions created by [Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
you have to use the Uri returned by with [DocumentFile.fromTreeUri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html#fromTreeUri%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri%29)

Comment: I actually have this permission, but for some reason, calling DocumentFile.fromFile(context,file).delete(); will always fail for me.

Comment: As far as I know, "doesn't give you any additional access" still holds true . If you have been given URI access to a full storage, and want File -> DocumentFile, you'll have to do some painfull URI building based on the tree uri you have access to and then created a DocumentFile from that. Look into the DocumentFile source code and look at the differences in URIs returned by FilePicker / Helper methods etc.

Comment: Why is it this way? And isn't this function considered useless because of this? You mean to tell me that I would need to traverse the file-tree for this?

Comment: I find it crazy too, but afaik this is what's available... Either traverse the tree or lookup AOSP code and make a function that constructs a working DocumentFile (it's possible, just very hacky).

Comment: It's just that many related functions about it are already quite a workaround. Just have a look at this code: https://github.com/jeisfeld/Augendiagnose/blob/master/AugendiagnoseLib/src/de/jeisfeld/augendiagnoselib/util/imagefile/FileUtil.java

Comment: I know it's frustrating, but I can't change that :). Mail me if you want to chat about this. Nice link, looks similar to my methods. Traversing the uri root as fallback is a nice touch. I build my methods mostly from AOSP code (ExternalStorageProvider and AOSP file picker).

Comment: When I grow up, I wish I would be able to understand most Google developer's decisions.