# How to create new file in secondary SD card of Android Lollipop device?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-external-storage, mediamuxer

In my app I use MediaMuxer to create a video file. Constructor of MediaMuxer requires absolute path of output file. Everything is ok with primary storage, but for secondary storage app doesn't work. As I check, in Lollipop user has to pick output directory in external storage, using new Intent ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE ([How to use the new SD card access API presented for Android 5.0 (Lollipop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744842/how-to-use-the-new-sd-card-access-api-presented-for-lollipop))
But on result of this Intent we get DocumentFile. I don't know how to create new video file with MediaMuxer and this DocumentFile. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

There is a method `createFile(String mimeType, String displayName)` - just call it on the [DocumentFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html) directory instance:

```
DocumentFile newFile = documentFileDir.createFile("application/octet-stream", fileName);
OutputStream os = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(newFile.getUri());
... // write your data
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but I don't think this answers the question. MediaMuxer only takes a String path or a FileDescriptor. Neither DocumentFile nor OutputStream are either of those things, so how can MediaMuxer be used with them?