# SD-Card access API Android for Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-sdcard

In this other question

[How to use the new SD card access API presented for Android 5.0 (Lollipop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744842/how-to-use-the-new-sd-card-access-api-presented-for-lollipop)

It is explained how to use the new API to access the "external SDCard".

But, how can I know the actual directory returned in the result activity?

I mean in function

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri treeUri = resultData.getData();
        DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);
```

......

How can I get the actual path where "Uri treeUri" points?

Thanks,
Francis.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get absolute path of selected directory?

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. My user interface shows the current directory so I need to know it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
FileUtil.getFullPathFromTreeUri(treeUri, this)
```

from

https://github.com/jeisfeld/Augendiagnose/blob/f24ddd7d3da4df94552ca0a9e658399602855a67/AugendiagnoseIdea/augendiagnoseLib/src/main/java/de/jeisfeld/augendiagnoselib/util/imagefile/FileUtil.java

to get the full path. Seperate the path using

```
final String[] seperated = treeUri.toString().split("\\/");
```

to get the current dir name.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the absolute path because the Documents API is designed to abstract this from you.

However, the `treeUri` does contain the relative path to the file. Try examining the Uri using [Uri#getPathSegments()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getPathSegments())