# Extra to enable the Show/Hide SD Card with Storage Access Framework (SAF)

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I am using the Storage Access Framework (SAF) :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

I would like to know if there is an extra to enable the Show SD Card option, that user can see in the overflow menu.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add

```
intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
```

But be aware that this is not part of the official API. So there is a good chance this will stop working in future Android versions.

The relevant Framework code can be found here:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.0_r1/com/android/documentsui/DocumentsActivity.java#255

Comment: Nice tip! It seems to be the only way to do it currently