# Is it possible to write to the sd card without a file picker on kitkat+

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat, android-sdcard, storage-access-framework

I want to delete files from the SD card root without a file picker.

After searching around for a couple of days,i haven't found a way to do this.But files apps ES file explorer have no problem,does anyone know why that is?

The closest thing i found would be this
[How to use the new SD-Card access API presented for Lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744842/how-to-use-the-new-sd-card-access-api-presented-for-lollipop)  but i have to use a file picker

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"/>



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Is file.delete() method not working?

Comment: correct it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you modified manifest file for WRITE_EXTERNAL permission?

Comment: yes, when i run it i get java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: Post your manifest file

Comment: change it to lower case letter as in my answer? Never seen permission written with uppercase letters.

Comment: @agilob wow I've had this problem for over 3 days and it turns i that was my problem. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide us some source code and tell what you tried.

Check if you can create new empty files:

```
    File newFile = new File("/storage/sdcard1/test");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Edit after comment:
Add this in your manifest above application tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: He can't delete a file, but delete() method doesn't throw any exception, trying to create a file would tell him and us more.

Comment: when i run this i get java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)