# OSMDroid offline map : exception with blank map on android device "fail to read directory on sdcard"

Tags: android

```
       MapView mapView = new MapView(this, 256); //constructor
       mapView.setClickable(true);
       mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
       setContentView(mapView); //displaying the MapView
       mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
       mapView.getController().setZoom(15); 
       mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(mLat, mLon));
       mapView.setUseDataConnection(true); 
       mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
```

I have made an offline map with Atlas creator using OSMDroid MapQuest

I have placed zip file inside Sdcard inside "osmdroid" folder.

But

When i run my android application there is excetion that

**fail to read directory

and showing "blank map" on my android device

Please please help.

Comment: Which android version are you using? do yo have declared read persmissions in android manifest?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Lollipop, you cannot read from any arbitrary directory from the SDCard. You have to do one of these:

- Request for permission through SAF to read from any directory on the sdcard
  : [How to use the new SD card access API presented for Android 5.0 (Lollipop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744842/how-to-use-the-new-sd-card-access-api-presented-for-lollipop/26765884#26765884)
- Write to your app specific folder on the sdcard by calling `context.getExternalFilesDirs` and choosing the sdcard path that is returned.