# Can't delete File with the File class

Tags: android, file, class

Im trying to delete a music file through my App but can't achieve that. Ive checked with

```
boolean exists = temp.exists();
boolean isFile = temp.isFile();
```

if there true and yes they are. These methods returns me true.
But when I come to the delete method :

```
boolean deleted = temp.delete();
```

It returns me False and the file is not getting deleted. There are no Exception throws just a false return to my deleted variable.

Im also using these permissons :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG"/>
```

Someone got an Idea for a solution ?
(Or other classes I can use ?)

Edit:
Thats my full code

```
File temp = new File(str_path);

boolean exists = temp.exists();
boolean isFile = temp.isFile();

if (exists)) {
    boolean deleted = temp.delete();
    if (deleted) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Successful deleted " + Title_Artist, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Not able to delete file " + Title_Artist, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

(And I checked while debuging if the object has his path in it and it have it)

Comment: What, exactly, is `temp` pointing to? What is the path? How did you create the `File` object?

Comment: Please post more of your code -

Comment: I updated my post. You can see now the whole code of my delete process in the Edit: section

Comment: who is this temp? where did you created it?

Comment: Please look at my Edit Daniel

Comment: Can you remove your phone from computer and try again?

Comment: Didnt helped sunlight ...

Comment: try creating your file by `File image = File.createTempFile(  name, ".jpg", str_path );`. thus you should be able to delete it

Comment: How should this help me ? I didnt get it

Comment: Have you used this file for anything else in your application? Maybe some thread is opened this file and OS block your delete operation? Have you tried to delete this file manually (using file manager), or use deleteOnExit() method?

Comment: If you're device is running marshmallow and your target sdk is 23 you will need to either use target sdk 22 or do that stupid permission request for this.

Comment: doubledeath yes I did not working

Answer (score 3):

Delete file music you must do two task:

1. Delete file in Storage.

   ```
   public static boolean delete(File path) {
       boolean result = true;
       if (path.exists()) {
           if (path.isDirectory()) {
               for (File child : path.listFiles()) {
                   result &= delete(child);
               }
               result &= path.delete(); // Delete empty directory.
           }
           if (path.isFile()) {
           result &= path.delete();
           }
           if (!result) {
               Log.e("Delete", "Delete failed;");
           }
           return result;
       } else {
           Log.e("Delete", "File does not exist.");
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Delete file from MediaStore:

   ```
   public static void deleteFileFromMediaStore(final ContentResolver contentResolver, final File file) {
       int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
       if (sdk >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
          String canonicalPath;
          try {
              canonicalPath = file.getCanonicalPath();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              canonicalPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
          }
          final Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
          final int result = contentResolver.delete(uri,
                   MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[]{canonicalPath});
          if (result == 0) {
              final String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
              if (!absolutePath.equals(canonicalPath)) {
               contentResolver.delete(uri,
                       MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[]{absolutePath});
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

You can reset/rescan MediaStore instead of do some code above.

Note: If you delete from SD card and android 4.4 +

> **Change for Android 4.4+** : Apps are not allowed to write (delete, modify
>   ...) to external storage except to their package-specific directories.

Comment: But the problem I dont understand is how other apps do it ? Ive tried it out I cant delete a specific file from extern but the app Shuffler for example can delete it.

Answer (score 2):

The path from your comment looks like the file is on a removable SD card. You need special permissions on Android 4.4+ to manage or delete files on an SD card. You will need to use [`DocumentFile#delete()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html#delete()).

For help accessing files on a removable SD card using DocumentFile see the following StackOverflow post:

[How to use the new SD card access API presented for Android 5.0 (Lollipop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744842/how-to-use-the-new-sd-card-access-api-presented-for-lollipop)

---

There is also a hack that might work without using `DocumentFile` as explained by the developer of FX file manager here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=52151865

Comment: What is "ContentUriUtil" in the hack ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are checking that the file exists, there can only be one reason you can not delete the file: you don't have permissions to do it.

An app can not delete system files, or files of other apps.

Comment: But how are other Music Player apps doing it ? All the permissons I need I used in my manifest right ?

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you are trying to delete? Just the paths of a few files.

Comment: /storage/extSdCard/Musik/neverlie_look.mp3

Comment: You can't edit files there, see this website: http://support.powerampapp.com/knowledgebase/articles/326024-can-t-edit-delete-files-on-sd-card-android-4-4

Comment: I just tried it with the app Shuffle (Which is sth like poweramp) and it does work ? So they are able to delete it

Comment: Am I supposed to move the file to my Phone storage and then delete it ? Or is it also not allowed to move files from extern Card

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your file path is

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                        + "/Music"
                        + "/"
                        + "song.mp3"
```

delete it like this

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getPath()
                        + "/Music");

if (dir.isDirectory()) {new File(dir, song.mp3).delete();}
```

if you want to delete all the files in music folder do this

```
if (dir.isDirectory()) {
                    String[] children = dir.list();
                    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                        new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
                    }
                }
```