# How to delete music files with their path android 11 - java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, delete-file

So I have a music player app. In which I want the user should be able to delete the music files which are not created by my app. I have the file path and I tried Using File.delete() but it always returns false. How can I delete the music files using their path. Please can someone help.
Path I am getting using File.getPath - **/storage/emulated/0/Samsung/Music/Over_the_horizon.mp3**

**My AndroidManifest.xml**

````
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.naman.musicplayer">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MusicPlayer">
        <activity
            android:name=".PlaySong"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

**Code I am using to delete the music**

     ``` @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
              File file = files.get(i);
    //files = new ArrayList<File>();
               boolean deleted = file.delete();
               return deleted;
                        }```
````

Comment: How are you getting the path? And can you put the route of the file you want to remove please?

Comment: I am getting the path using the File.getPath()

Comment: Is this file a directory? Could you edit your question and paste what you getting with File.getPath()?

Comment: I edited please check

Comment: Have you checked if the file exists before deleting?

Comment: Yes it exists. I have checked.

Comment: Edit again the question please, with your Manifest and your piece of code of deleting the file .

Comment: Done it. You can check

Comment: have you check file path exist or not..? if (file.exists()) {
            result = file.delete();
        }

Comment: There's no if condition checking if this file exist @namanop, have you debugged it to know it?

Comment: file.exists() returns true but file.delete() returns false

Comment: Did it appear a pop up to accept the write access to storage permission? have you accepted it?

Comment: It asked permission when I opened the app for the first time. I accepted it.

Comment: follow this Link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659789/11138845

Comment: Not working. @Badshah

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34919240/11138845

Comment: That also does not work @Badshah

Comment: In logcat error it says Delete failed;

Comment: Can someone please help me

Comment: Android version of used device? Can you create a file there? You are not usinf file.exists() and file.canWrite in your code.

Comment: which OS have you deleted Music path..?

Comment: I am using Android 11 device. Samsung Phone

Comment: try this  File dir = getFilesDir(); File file = new File(dir, "my_filename"); boolean deleted = file.delete(); i have guild for this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68080701/11138845

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
File file = new File(path);

if (!file.exists()) return;

if (file.isFile()) {
file.delete();
return;
}

File[] fileArr = file.listFiles();

if (fileArr != null) {
for (File subFile : fileArr) {
if (subFile.isDirectory()) {
deleteFile(subFile.getAbsolutePath());
}

if (subFile.isFile()) {
subFile.delete();
}
}
}

file.delete();
```

`path` is a `String`

Answer (score 1):

> > /storage/emulated/0/Samsung/Music/Over_the_horizon.mp3

That is a file not created by your app.

On an Android 11 device you cannot read/write/delete such a file with classic file system tools as your app is not the owner.

File.canRead() and File.canWrite() would tell you that.

To delete the file use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to let the user pick the file first.

Another possibility is to get the mediastore uri for that file and then use `MediaStore.createDeleteRequest()` for the delete.

Comment: Can you tell me a little more about MediaStore.createDeleteRequest