# Can't see files stored in sdcard using Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android

I have a problem with android emulator. I need to choose a file from sdcard e send it to a WS. The running emulator is a Nexus 5 with android 6.
I've searched everyehere, but none of the solution works.
I use this code to open a file explorer:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("file/*");
            startActivity(intent);
```

but when I run the code, I can't find the file on the sdcard.
I put the files with adb istructions and in the File Explorer of Android Device Monitor I can see the files.
Farther, iI can see the picture if I search in the Gallery of the emulator.
Which is the problem? Where is my error?
I tried also Dev Tool>Media Provider

Answer (score 0):

Add the following permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I have added the permission and now I can see the file but I can't select it. The file is locked and the permission for the file is: -rwxrwx---, I need to change it?

Comment: you can try to replace the READ with WRITE permission but I don't think it will do anything.
Try to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744842/how-to-use-the-new-sd-card-access-api-presented-for-lollipop

Comment: If I use Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, I have a warning  and I can't pick the path of th file because I can access to the directory but not to the full path of the file. If I use ACTION_GET_CONTENT I'm unable to select the file, I can see it but I can't select it. I need to open the file explorer, select the file and return to my activity and pick the full path of the file. How I can reach this?