# How to remove A file from removable/secondary SD card

Tags: java, android

I want to delete a file from the removable sd card, I tried many ways but nothing did the job.

Tried:

```
file.delete();
```

and

```
File file = new File(selectedFilePath);
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

and

```
DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromFile(file);
documentFile.delete();
```

and

```
DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(context.getContentResolver(),
  Uri.fromFile(file );
```

none of which deletes the file

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> yes i added these permissions @jackz314

Comment: files.delete() , don't do any thing

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.ContentProviderClient.call(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference

this error appers when i use this 

DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(context.getContentResolver(),
  Uri.fromFile(file );

@jackz314

Comment: i am trying to work on file explore and  i could use the file for many things,
for example one of the paths
/storage/extSdCard/Download
@jackz314

Comment: it returns true @jackz314

Comment: You know what, I totally forgot about the restrictions Android imposes, look at CommonsWare's answer, I think he explains it quite clearly.

Comment: ok, thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

> I want to delete a file from the removable sd card

In general, you can't.

*If* you put the file in one of the `Context` locations (`getExternalFilesDirs()`, etc.), then you should be able to delete it, using `delete()` on a `File` object.

If this is some other file, you do not have permission to do anything with it, including delete it.

And on Android Q, [you will not have much access to external or removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/03/25/death-external-storage-what-now.html) at all.

You are welcome to use the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`) and work with content that way.

> i am trying to work on file explore

Android Q is severely restricting that entire app category. I recommend that you build something else.

Comment: the proplem that i am facing on android lolipop and up.
is there any solution for these devices?

Comment: @aboahmad: Use the Storage Access Framework. See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) for more about how removable storage works with Android.

Comment: for lolipop and up, you would need to put it in the "Context locations" like described in the answer (or just set the "context location" where the file is, e.g., the entire external storage). Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26765884/8170714)

Comment: i'll check these context locations , and hope it works, thanks a lot @jackz314